# create a loop function in google sheets/apps script using a list of Ids within import range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a for loop function in google apps script to use a list of Id's as a variable inside a query function.

The query bellow imports and generate a list of sheet ID's

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1b9_rVjCeGEQE9xeerjfXIvWafEpOGvNo2omWTqDn000";"mysheet!A:K")};"select Col1 OFFSET 1";0)
```

The results is a list of IDs, for example:

1QamM0J0CTPD1f8Ovrk81lH2NUJ9Ll8E77hnchahk_00

1bsLJpi5VqU0pPj2jp7AOCz7SuWYMFAWgGSdnlcyR_000

18OQmdHMlavZQhnup86S2J0D7FG7qhCTFylwdwrHd_000

I need to create a for loop function that uses that list to generate a result for every Id. Something like the code bellow:

```
list_of_Ids =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1b9_rVjCeGEQE9xeerjfXIvWafEpOGvNo2omWTqDn000";"mysheet!A:K")};"select Col1 OFFSET 1";0)

function myFunction() {
  for(var i=0,list_of_Ids>0,i++){
QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(""&list_of_Ids&"";"sheet1!B40:K40")};"select Col1,Col2,Col3  OFFSET 1";0)
  }
}
```

The expected result is something like this:

[image: Result image]

Appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: Can you clarify where you want this to end up and what the list_of_ids variable outputs? An example spreadsheet would help a lot.

Comment: Hi Luke. I need a query result. In the param import range,  I need to use  a list of IDs,querying each one in a sequence, so I thought a for loop would  be a solution.

Comment: Gotcha, but where are you importing the ids to? What range? And are the id's across columns only? And is there a reason you need to combine QUERY with IMPORTRANGE?

Comment: The list of Ids are generated by a query. This list should be used as a variable in the import range query of the function I am trying to create. Yes, the Ids, are a column only.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit to my answer, you're closer. The variable length cannot have a sheet in the getRange(). But also I made a mistake, it should be setFormula not setFunction.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var length = ss.getSheetByName("IDS").getRange("A2:A95").getValues().filter(String).length;

for(var i=1; i <= length; i++){

var id = ss.getSheetByName("IDS").getRange(i +1,1).getValue()

ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1+1,2).setFormula('=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("' + id + '";sheet1!B40:K40");"select Col1,Col2,Col3 OFFSET 1"; 0)')
  }}
```

Comment: Hi Luke. I think there is a problem in the code. I got a message error: Exception: You do not have permission to call setFormula. Maybe it is because to access data in an external spreadsheet using the query formula you need to allow permission to access and you are not allowed to use custom function to access external data. Is there a way around it ?

Comment: Hi @JonathanLivingstonSeagull. Yes indeed you cannot call call a service that needs authorization from a custom function. But in this case you do not have a custom function. This is a script that should be run directly. You could run it from the script editor. Or, if you want to you can create a menu item or button to run it that's also an option. Please let me know if that helps.